# Apache Commons: IOUtils.write - how to restrict bytes-stream during write

Tags: java, file, apache-commons

I realised reading a file into bytes-array with next writing this array to file in another directory by the following approach:

```
try(FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(attachFile)){
ZipOutputStream zipOutputStream = null;
byte[] bytes = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
int length;
while ((length = fis.read(bytes)) >= 0) {
      zipOutputStream.write(bytes, 0, length);
   }
}
```

And this code done well - in target directory appear new file with the relevant content (for example: "abcd").

Further I tried to improve my approach through ApacheCommons abilities.

```
try(FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(attachFile)){
  ZipOutputStream zipOutputStream = null;
  byte[] bytes = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
  IOUtils.read(fis, bytes);
  IOUtils.write(bytes, zipOutputStream);
}
```

But this approach entails the problem: in target directory the new file appeals, but this written content is irrelevant. Besides the written text (for example: "abcd") it contains some unreadable unencoded symbols, and I see the warning about problem with encoding.

I suppose this problem is related to the fact, that some excess bytes read and/or write to OutpumStream. And this problem (probably) arise due to  the fact I don't restrict read and write-operations, applying IOUtils (second approach).

And in first approach I restrict the write of byte-array in OutputStream by size of length-variable:

```
 while ((length = fis.read(bytes)) >= 0)
```

If problem in that I must have a way to restrict the write by tools of AppacheCommons.
But I don't see any way to do so in IOUtils-methods.

Answer (score 1):

The way to copy an `InputStream` to an `OutputStream` using `IOUtils` is this:

```
try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(attachFile);
    ZipOutputStream zos = /* open it */;) 
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
    IOUtils.copy(fis, zos, buffer);
}
```

Note that a `ZipOutputStream` needs to be closed to cause it to compress and write out the final block.  A `flush` is not sufficient.

---

However, there is better way to copy a file to an output stream that (also) doesn't rely on any 3rd-party libraries such as Apache Commons IO:

```
Path path = /* path for input file */
try (ZipOutputStream zos = /* open output stream */;) 
{
    Paths.copy(path, zos);
}
```

The `Path` and `Paths` classes have been part of the Java SE class library since Java 7.

---

So what is wrong with your second attempt?

1. If the input file contains more than `BUFFER_SIZE` bytes, the `IOUtils.read(fis, bytes)` call won't read the entire file.
2. As you noted `IOUtils.write(bytes, zipOutputStream)` writes the entire buffer, and there is no way to tell it to do a partial write.

Basically, if you want to use `IOUtils.read` and `IOUtils.write`, you need to find out how many bytes there are in the input file and set the buffer to *exactly* that size.  However, that is not a good idea.  If the file is very large, the heap may be too small for the buffer.  If the file size changes while you are copying it, then you are liable to either not copy it all, or write a bunch of binary zeros at the end.

Comment: Sorry for delay in reaction! Your answer is absolutely usefull!